# Why V1/guest-carts/{cart-Id}/ PUT api is not move guest cart item to customer cart in magento-2.2.7?

Tags: customer, quoteitem, magento2.2.7

I want to move guest cart item into customer cart by using this [PUT] /V1/guest-carts/{cart-Id}/  . But it give {"message": "Cannot assign customer to the given cart. You don't have permission for this operation."}. Why it can't move item to customer cart. Please help me to solve it.

Comment: If we pass customer token in header,then it show 400 error " message":"Cannot assign customer to the given cart. Customer already has active cart." . If we not passed customer token in header, then it give error     "message": "Consumer is not authorized to access %resources".

Comment: Anybody have same issue?